# Excel sheets select first row with c#

Tags: c#, excel, linq

I want to select excel sheets first row using interop object. How can i do ?

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(directory, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
var List<string> tempList= range[1,*].Value.ToList();
```

I want to write similar as abow. How can I write this situation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
xlWorkSheet.Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow.Value;
```

Comment: [Use the Range property instead of this method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range.aspx)

Comment: also i want to use toList() method. is it possible?

Comment: Just change xlWorkSheet.Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow.Value;
to xlWorkSheet.Range["A1", "A1"].EntireRow.Value;

Comment: @AlbertoCláudioMandlate hello, may i know what is the difference between the code and your alternative? it looks like the only difference is parenthesis / square brackets

Answer (score 8):

There is `Rows` property using which you can access first row of particular range:

```
var firstRow = range.Rows[1];
```

Comment: Could you write example? please

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. To select the first row of excel sheet and apply style bold

```
 xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
```