# How to set cursor at start postion

Tags: c#, winforms

I have following below image and code. I am exporting my data into an Excel file using RadGridViewExcelExporter Telerik Control. I have the below code. I want to set the cursor from starting point but my cursor stops ending point (yellow highlight in image) or last record. When I open the Excel sheet it is open from the last record.

How do open the Excel sheet with start point?

```
exporter = new RadGridViewExcelExporter();

BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
worker.RunWorkerAsync(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
exporter.Progress += new ProgressHandler(exportProgress);
Cursor previousCursor = Cursor.Current = Cursors.AppStarting;

Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
Cursor.Current = previousCursor;
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What's the code to export to excel file? May be a simple thing at the end of that code to select cell(1,1) (or something like that in the library you use) might do the trick.

Comment: where do you want to set your cursor? the image you provide just shows a part of a excel sheet. but you tagged the question with winforms. so what exactly do you want to archieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excell sheets select first row with c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113766/excell-sheets-select-first-row-with-c-sharp)

Comment: i have RadGridViewExcelExporter(); telerik control that i use

Comment: when i open the file its show start from start point but it shows last of record